# How to build a cell reference using index/match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, index-match

I'm trying to use index match to pull some data but I want to protect against future re-arranging of columns

so in my index/match formula, rather than hardcode column C:C, I'd like to embed another match function that searches the row containing all column headers for the header called "Grouping" for example.

```
=INDEX(MasterSheet!B:B,MATCH(Sheet1!D4,MasterSheet!D:D,0))
```

How would i replace the `MasterSheet!B:B` portion with a dynamic search. I know i can use `MATCH(C3,MasterSheet!Print_Titles,0)` where C3 = "Grouping", but Im having trouble turning that into the reference

Comment: what is the range of `Print_Titles`?  You can use the third criterion to set the relative column number

Comment: print tiles is just row 4 as that will always contain the column headers

Comment: Then use: `=INDEX(MasterSheet!A:XFD,MATCH(Sheet1!D4,MasterSheet!D:D,0),MATCH(C3,MasterSheet!Print_Titles,0))`